# RegEx Table variable undefined

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Why is this RegEx table variable not working?

I am looking for this string:

```
_form_23
```

inside this Form Element string:

```
HTMLDivElement: html > body.customize-support#bg > div.page-wraper > div.page-content.bg-white > div.content-block#content-area > div.section-area.bg-gray > div.container > div.row.contact-bx-area2 > div.col-lg-8.col-md-12.wow.fadeIn.section-sp2 > div.form-area-box.ajax-form.p-lr30.p-sm-lr5 > div.row.placeani > div.col-lg-12 > div.form-white > div._form_23 > form._form._form_23._inline-form._dark#_form_64633F35D8028_ > div._form-thank-you
```

Even though the Form Element string contains "_form_23" twice (and regex validator confirmed it), the variable shows undefined.

[image]

What am I missing?

These are my RegEx table variable settings:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding wildcard modifiers before and after `_form_23` to match all before/after characters? Something like `.*_form_23.*` might work